# Load in passed HTML using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery

I have a function like: `uiModal.simpleModal('<p>This is some content</p>');`

Which should call a modal with the passed data as the modal content. e.g. (note I haven't added the modalHtml as it's not relevant to this question).

```
simpleModal: function (data) {

    var responseHtml = data;

    // Append the modal HTML to the DOM
    var modalInstance = $('body').append(modalHtml);

    // Dynamically load in the passed data from the call
    $.ajax({
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function (responseHtml) {
            $(modalInstance).find('.uiModalContent').html($(responseHtml));
            $(modalInstance).find('.uiModalContent').removeClass('loading');

            isModalSuccess = true;
        },
        error: function () {
            $(modalInstance).find('.uiModalContent').html('<div class="message error"><h2>Unknown Error</h2> Please contact support</p></div>');
            $(modalInstance).find('.uiModalContent').removeClass('loading');
        }
    });

    $(modalInstance).find('.ModalClose').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.uiModal').fadeOut(function () { $(this).parents('.uiModalWrapper').remove() });
    });
},
```

However it doesn't load in the data! Can someone point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't told your ajax method where to load the data from.

You need to pass in a URL from which you will load your data:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://www.example.com/jsonRequest",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function (responseHtml) {}
});
```

**UPDATE**

Given your comment below it seem that you might have a slight misunderstanding of what ajax is designed for.

In your case you already have the data for the modal window and so you can use it without the need for an ajax call.

```
    $(modalInstance).find('.uiModalContent').html($(responseHtml));
    $(modalInstance).find('.uiModalContent').removeClass('loading');
```

If you also need to check that the data exists in your `respoonseHtml` variable then you can do that with a simply `if` statement:

```
if(responseHtml.length > 0)
{
        $(modalInstance).find('.uiModalContent').html($(responseHtml));
        $(modalInstance).find('.uiModalContent').removeClass('loading');
}
else
{
   $(modalInstance).find('.uiModalContent')
     .html('Error message here');
   $(modalInstance).find('.uiModalContent').removeClass('loading');

}
```

Comment: There is no URL, the content is being passed in the function call

Comment: It isn't. The ajax method is for retriving data from a URL. You're doing this the wrong way. Forget about the ajax part, you don't need it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Why I do not see any URL for the ajax call.
There must be some url you want to hit, to retrieve data, if not then why you are doing $.ajax ?

Comment: There is no URL, the content is being passed in the function call

Comment: If your passing the content, why use AJAX?